# Cannot find datasheet for CMOS sensor

Tags: cmos, camera, ccd

can anyone please help me identify a datasheet for that CCD/CMOS sensor ? on the camera it says CCD but i highly doubt it since it's 4 dollars.

it's a reverse camera and i want to remove the overlay, tried to desolder the EEPROM and it just freezes and doesn't work.

EDIT : HERE IS THE EEPROM

> https://anonymousfiles.io/owjwdNgk/

[image: BACK OF THE SENSOR]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems unlikely that the reverse overlay is in the sensor...

Comment: Maybe it’s a clone https://www.gophotonics.com/search/cmos-image-sensors?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq6uxzq2V7wIV5QiICR2sEQqMEAMYASAAEgLrtPD_BwE

Comment: @brhans no the overlay is in it. It reads the EEPROM for the configuration and there is a byte which has that config wether to display overlay only or display units ir stop or mirror the image.. look up on google removing reverse camera overlay. Lots of info on it. I read the eeprom and have an i2c programmer. I just cannot find a datasheet and desoldering didn't work. I will try to bruteforce and change byte by byte and see.. buuuut tooo much time

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 yes 100% it is a clone. I tried verifying the eeprom against lots of prolific datasheets and none match the data inside.. thank you so much for that search it will really help I'll check the rest of the datasheets.  Also do you know how many inches is that sensor ? Like where do you measure it the whole sensor glass or just the small area on the inside with the actual sensor ?

Comment: Just the CMOS area , use a microscope to estimate pixels, but finding the source will be like a needle in a haystack